# Repeat ping every 30 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, ping

I created a **Windows Forms** application to ping a list of Ip addresses, then i used a `Timer` to repeat the ping every `30` seconds. This is the code i used:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 30000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += button1_Click;

    }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        pingResults.Clear();
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.1");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.2");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.3");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.4");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.5");
        ipAddress.Add("10.100.1.100");

        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" + i, true)[0]);
        }

        Parallel.For(0, ipAddress.Count(), (i, loopState) =>
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipAddress[i].ToString());

            this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
            {
                pictureBoxList[i].BackColor = (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            });

        });

    }
private void button1_Click(object sender,ElapsedEventArgs e )
    {            
      backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();                      
    }
```

But i got this error message:

> Error 1   No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

I tried a lot of examples but i didn't get how to use the `Timer`. what is the problem here or is there any other way to repeat the Ping?

Comment: The parameters of the button1_Click method don't match to what te compiler expects. It should be: void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

Comment: In that `backgroundWorker1_DoWork`, you don't want to `Sleep`. The activation interval is already managed by the timer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, note that `Button.Clicked` and `Timer.Elapsed` have *different signatures*; you, probably, want

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 30000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed; // not button1_Click
}

...

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{            
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();                      
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Or you can get rid of `timer_Elapsed` at all with a help of *lambda function*:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 30000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => {backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();}; 
}

...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{  
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with the timer is a perfect idea. Anyhow now you try to activate the timer with a button which will not work properly.

Try this example from the microsoft documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -1):

Looking on the definition of `System.EventHandler` (at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netframework-4.8), we see that it's:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
[System.Serializable]
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

It's a delegate, which takes one parameter of type `System.EventArgs` and one of type `object`. Looking on your code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

We see that your event handler receives an `object` and an `ElapsedEventArgs`, which is a subclass of `EventArgs`. But you can't use it, since the compiler expect `EventArgs` (the opposite, superclass instead of subclass, of course allowed). This is the meaning of the error message:

> Error 1 No overload for 'button1_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

I (the compiler) expected a method matches the signature of `System.EventHandler`, but didn't got.